# Installing Vue-CLI, VUE.JS, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, proxy, vue.js, vue-cli

I am trying to Install the VUE CLI into my laptop but it gives following errors.

```
λ npm install -g vue-cli
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.nmpjs.org/vue-cli failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 218.93.250.18:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ABDUR REHMAN KHALID\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-01-29T07_46_22_789Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Vue issue. It seems like your registry is set to the wrong url. Set registry to the correct url with:

`npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to install `vue-cli` then you should try this.

```
sudo npm install --global vue-cli
```